# Java Enum with field of type enum

Tags: java, enums, enumeration, abstraction

Not sure how to phrase the question so please feel free to update it.
I have a complex enumeration which references other enumerations based on the enumeration value, like this:

```
public enum EFormSw {

    OBJ_KEY_LIST("Object Keys", EObjKeyType.class),
    OBJ_NOTE_LIST("Object Notes",  EObjNoteType.class);

public final String label;
public final Class</*"E is an Enum"*/> enumType;

// Constructor...
```

What I want to be able to do in another class is to write something like

```
EFormSw.OBJ_KEY_LIST.enumType.values().someThingElse().
```

Which is only possible if its clear by the field type that this is an enumeration.

Is there any way to achieve this at all?

Comment: Do you mean something like `EFormSw.OBJ_KEY_LIST.enumType.values()`? I don't see how you can access `enumType` directly from `EFormSw`. You'd have to use `OBJ_KEY_LIST` or `OBJ_NOTE_LIST`.

Comment: @Sweeper: yes of course, that was a typo. Thank you for pointing that out!

Comment: Then it raises the question of, if you know that it’s `OBJ_KEY_LIST`, why can’t you just do `EObjKeyType.values()` directly? If you don’t know which constant it is, then you would only get an array of `Enum<?>`s, since each constant has a different type of `enumType` and you don’t know which one it is. Is that actually useful to you?

Comment: The code snippet is a simplication of the subject to make the issue more precise for the SO question. In the actual code there will be an iteration over the EFormSw enumeration, leading to this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make `enumType` a `Class<? extends Enum<?>>`:

```
enum EFormSw {

  OBJ_KEY_LIST("Object Keys", EObjKeyType.class),
  OBJ_NOTE_LIST("Object Notes", EObjNoteType.class);

  private final String label;
  private final Class<? extends Enum<?>> enumType;

  EFormSw(String label, Class<? extends Enum<?>> enumType) {
    this.label = label;
    this.enumType = enumType;
  }

  public String getLabel() {
    return label;
  }

  public Class<? extends Enum<?>> getEnumType() {
    return enumType;
  }
}
```

When you are looping through the values of `EFormSw`, you can use `getEnumConstants` to get an `Enum<?>[]` representing the enum values of the enum type, but you won't be able to do much with it, because you don't know which exact enum type it is:

```
for (EFormSw constant: EFormSw.values()) {
    Enum<?>[] values = constant.getEnumType().getEnumConstants();
}
```

(You can still call most of the methods declared in `java.lang.Enum` and `java.lang.Object` on the array elements, so if that's all you need, you can just use that.)

If you want to use some common functionality shared between `EObjKeyType` and `EObjNoteType`, you can extract all the common functionality into a common interface that they both implement:

```
interface EObjType {
    // ...
}

enum EObjKeyType implements EObjType {
    // ...
}

enum EObjNoteType implements EObjType {
    // ...
}
```

Then change `enumType` to:

```
private final Class<? extends EObjType > enumType;
```

Now you can get a `EObjType[]` instead.